# VS 2012 HTML5 JS project in Windows 7

Tags: html, windows-7, visual-studio-2012

I have a new dilemma. I have been tasked with looking into moving our Silverlight project into an HTML5 project. Nice!

Well, I downloaded the sample solution from the link below and tried to load it into VS 2012. The Services project loaded fine, but the DataBinding project (a JS project I believe) did not load. The reason stated I need Windows 8 or higher. I currently have Windows 7 SP 1 (64 bit).

Is there a setting or configuration I need to modify to allow this type of project to load? I appreciate any and all input on this. Thanks!

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Accessing-WCF-in-HTML5-and-0d247ef8

Answer (score 1):

The project is using WinJS which makes calls into Windows 8.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7437563/2249535

You can always open up the files individually and replace WinJS calls with jQuery calls but would still need to use a different project type to open in Visual Studio