# trying to load page with WinJS controls into IE 10.0

Tags: windows-runtime, winjs, internet-explorer-10

From VS2012, I right click on default.html page and choose to run this page in IE (10.0). Problem is that any WinJS controls that I have on the page aren't been displayed. I get a warning about Allowing ActiveX script where I allow to run the ActiveX script. Can windows 8 store app build with javascript should be able to run in IE 10.0?

Comment: check this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7437508/winjs-in-the-browser)

Comment: thanks. Not sure how can I mark your comment as answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WinJS is not meant to be a browser based application.
Windows Store apps are meant *solely* to be run in the WinRT environment.

If you explore WinJS, you'll see it calls into the Windows namespace which are the actual WinRT JavaScript projections - ie the translations from the C++ COM based API into  in this case JavaScript.

So then the next question is what are you trying to accomplish? If you have a common code base to run in the browser, then don't have dependencies on WinJS or the built in style sheets.

Remember though,Windows Store apps have specific design recommendations that may not be the best for a browser based application, although thats your call.

If you post separately what you are trying to accomplish though to run in the browser and in your Windows Store app, we can try to help you make the best design decision.

Since that is a separate question than what's provided here, I'd say sign up for App Builder http://aka.ms/stackbuilder and check out the free design guidance you get from there, plus check my profile, I'm available for free time each week (oHours)  and would be happy to go over this with you via skype, phone, etc

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't, firstly due to licence of winjs (details here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithhtml5/thread/dbdabf29-206d-4d93-a491-b5e8fcd6a920/) and secondly because winjs is rather tightly coupled with winrt. 
One alternative I found is http://www.bluesky.io/ which allows you to run winjs compatible code in browser. Not sure how it works in practice though.